# ACL issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, acl

I have this ACL in my module:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <report>
                    <children>
                        <modulename translate="title">
                            <title>Reports (SQL)</title>
                            <children>
                                <edit translate="title">
                                    <title>Add/Edit Reports</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </edit>
                            </children>
                        </modulename>
                    </children>
                </report>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

I have some reports where my url  is like:

```
adminhtml_customreport/viewtable/report_id/30/
```

or

```
adminhtml_customreport/viewtable/report_id/31/
```

is there a way to assign them to a specific role ?  if  Yes  , how  ?  All idea is welcomed .

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do this is to create ACL paths for each one that won't specifically match a controller path. To use your example:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <report>
                    <children>
                        <modulename translate="title">
                            <title>Reports (SQL)</title>
                            <children>
                                <edit translate="title">
                                    <title>Add/Edit Reports</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </edit>
                                <report_30 translate="title">
                                    <title>Report name</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </report_30>
                                <report_31 translate="title">
                                    <title>Report name</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </report_31>
                                <report_32 translate="title">
                                    <title>Report name</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </report_32>
                                <!-- And so on, for each report -->
                            </children>
                        </modulename>
                    </children>
                </report>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Then, in the controller `_isAllowed()` method, you can check for the requested report id vs. the path for each report, like this:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    $reportId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('report_id');

    switch ($reportId) {
        case '30':
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('report/modulename/report_30');
        case '31':
            ...
    }
}
```

Remember that ACL routes don't have to exactly correspond to controller routes.